How to access appsettings param inside .html file
In my .NET 6.0 / C# project, I have variable defined as
{  
    "Address": {
        "AddressLine1": "220 E. Yut Drive Suite 20",
        "AddressLine2": "giuuiu, CA 85679"
    },
    "AddressLine3": "22qwewqe"
}

I need to access addressLines in 1 of the html files defined in project. I have tried below ways but none worked.
  <p class=MsoNormal>
      <span style='mso-bookmark:_Hlk45183937'>
         <i><%$ AppSettings: Address.AddressLine1 %><o:p></o:p></i> 
      </span>
      <span style='mso-bookmark:_Hlk45183937'>
          <i><%$ appsettings: AddressLine3 %><o:p></o:p></i>
      </span>
      <span style='mso-bookmark:_Hlk45183937'>
          <i><%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddressLine3"]%><o:p></o:p></i>
      </span>
      <%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AddressLine3")%>
  </p>

I need to know how can I access these params inside html file

This seems like it wouldn't be the best way to solve this problem. Follow this tutorial to see a different approach

Usually in ASP.NET there's IConfiguration object that is dependency injected, that holds values from appsettings. This then could be injected into razor view with @inject IConfiguration configuration

Trick it with a Route to a Controllers Get method that returns your HTML with the settings embedded.
[HttpGet]
[Route("hello.html")]
public IActionResult YourHtmlFile(
{
    string htmlContent = "<html><body><h1>Hello, world!</h1></body></html>";
    return Content(htmlContent, "text/html");
})


If you you mean .cshtml, you could inject IConfiguration directly
@inject IConfiguration configuraion

@configuraion.GetSection("Address").GetSection("AddressLine1").Value
@configuraion["Address:AddressLine1"]

By the way <%$ %>is syntax for webform which is not used asp.net core 6.0.
